# How to set a custom field when uploading an array with gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm uploading an array of images with gridfs. I need to set a custom field to be able to get the images in the same order that they were organized in the application.

I can't simply sort by `uploadDate` because depending on the size of the image it may take more or less time to upload.

```
let formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append("imagem", this.filesToUpload);
```

controller:

```
router.post('/upload', upload.array('imagem'), function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

I looked at the [documentation - files.metadata](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) but still could not get into any solution how to set the custom field.

Comment: You could use `formData.append(name, value, filename);` instead of `formData.append(name, value);` and generate the name yourself allowing you to generate a numbered suffix for every file in the same order they were inserted.